# Не получается передать всё из коллекции в класс и TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Пытаюсь передать данные в класс и вывести в TreeView, но получаю не то, что хотелось и причину понять не могу.

Сам класс:

```
  public class Person
    {
       readonly List<Person> _children = new List<Person>();
        public IList<Person> Children
        {
            get { return _children; }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
      }
```

Database.cs

```
ObservableCollection<Person> users = new ObservableCollection<Person>
            {
                new Person { Name = "Bill"},
                new Person { Name = "Tom"},
                new Person { Name = "Alice"}
            };


            foreach (var qq in users)
            {

                str = new List<string>() { qq.Name };
                foreach (string s in str)
                {
                    string returnIP = s;
                    retList.Add(returnIP);
                }
            }

           // var results = String.Join(", ", retList.ToArray());
            return new Person
            {
                Name = retList.ToString(),
              
            };
```

при точке остановы на return new Person получаю :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в TreeView:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается что в дерево у меня приходит только одна запись из всей коллекции, почему так, как исправить?
заранее спасибо за любую посильную помощь

Comment: Покажите разметку, к чему привязка в XAML. Опишите задачу, которую решаете, какой ожидается результат. Я вижу, что вы пишете странный код, но он настолько странный, что исходную задачу угадать не получается.

Comment: [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61731042/12888024)

Comment: Задача: построить TreeView. Есть коллекция users, которая должна превратиться в treeView
разметка XAML 
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>

Comment: Вы возвращаете нового Person, и даёте ему имя retList.ToString(), а это как раз "Generic.List". То что вы делаете, по-сути бессмысленно, т.к. вы сначала создаёте List<Person>, извлекаете имена персон, и пытаетесь снова создать персону передав ему имя... Без контекста, куда возвращается ответ (return new Person...) - невозможно понять что вам нужно сделать.

Comment: Покажите в вопросе разметку `TreeView` полностью. Покажите свойство, к чему привязываете `TreeView`. Покажите метод, который возвращает `Person` целиком и так же код, из которого он вызывается. Не пишите код в комментариях, вопрос можно редактировать - кнопка "править".